# Visual Studio xtree _STL_VERIFY(this->_Getcont(), "cannot increment value-initialized map/set iterator");

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting a visual studio error during debugging that occurs only in "xtree" on this line:

```
_STL_VERIFY(this->_Getcont(), "cannot increment value-initialized map/set iterator");
```

According to the call back, this line of the actual code seems to be what triggers it:

```
for (map<string, vector<tm>>::iterator it = m_taskreports.begin(); it != m_taskreports.end(); ++it) {
```

This only happens when I run the code in visual studio, and I'm not sure why it's occurring, this seems to be a pretty standard map iterator as far as I can tell.

---

OK I tried this:

```
for (auto it = m_taskreports.begin(); it != m_taskreports.end(); it++) {
```

And got the same error. I then went back to the old iterator and added this before it:

```
if (m_taskreports.size() > 1) {
```

And added an else statement that basically does the same thing, but only with the first element. And it works, I just don't get why this is happening. Adding this if condition feels unnecessary since it worked fine outside of VS and it feels like this is more complicated that it needs to be.

(Also I'm using 2017 VS)

Comment: Can you provide more information? What version of visual studio are you using? Can you use C++11 (I would strongly suggest using auto for iterators) ? Maybe show a initialization of this map if you can. As far as I can tell in VS 2017 15.7 There is no _STL_VERIFY in xtree. Are you using STL from visual studio or some of your own (like EASTL)

Comment: I suggest that you simplify the problem to a reproducable example. Chances are, you'll find your bug before you have it reduced to StackOverflow-suitable example.

Comment: I added my attempt to OP.

Answer (score 1):

We ran across this same error, and I thought I'd enter my answer for others to see, because I could not really find any resources about this message.  In my case, it was a concurrent modification problem.  Thread1 was modifying a map while Thread2 was using it.

Comment: Awesome comment.  I had this same problem until I made sure I wasn't sorting on zero items in a concurrent situation.  Fixed the crashes.  Save me some real time.  A bit different, I know, but it got me thinking.